# Show convergence of the series of functions $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{n^\alpha (1+nx^2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

> Show convergence of the series of functions $\sum_{n=1}^\infty
> \frac{x}{n^\alpha (1+nx^2)}$ on $\mathbb{R}$, where $\alpha > \frac{1}{2}$

**My attempt**:

It suffices to show that for every fixed point $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty
\frac{x}{n^\alpha (1+nx^2)}$ of real numbers converges.

For $x = 0$, convergence is trivial.

Let $x \neq 0$. Then, we have:

$$\frac{1}{n^\alpha (1+nx²)} \leq \frac{1}{n^\alpha nx²} = \frac{1}{n^{1 + \alpha}x²}$$

and because the series $\sum\frac{1}{n^{1+ \alpha}}$ converges, the series $\sum \frac{1}{n^{1 + \alpha}x²}$ converges as well and by the comparison test the series $\sum\frac{1}{n^\alpha (1+nx²)}$ converges as well. Hence, we deduce that $\sum\frac{x}{n^\alpha (1+nx²)}$ is convergent for a fixed $x \neq 0$

Is this correct?

Comment: It is correct! Great job!

Comment: Just curious. Why do we need $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}?$

Comment: I think to make sure the hyperharmonic series converges.

Comment: $\alpha > 0$ would work too, I think

Comment: Yes, I don't know why they chose specifically this value for $\alpha$

Comment: you can use this inequality also $$\frac{x}{n^\alpha (1+nx^2)} \leq \frac{|x|}{n^\alpha nx^2} = \frac{1}{n^{1 + \alpha}|x|}$$

Comment: Do not forget to mention that the terms are nonnegative in comparison test.

Comment: yes that's why i left out the x in the numerator, although this is a constant